# Question about the CPU "Ryzen 9 7950X3D"

Tags: processor, ryzen

I bought a new PC: my mainboard is the "ProArt X670E-CREATOR WIFI", and the CPU is the "Ryzen 9 7950X3D".

According to the homepage of ASUS, the mainboard supports my CPU only since BIOS-version 1303:

https://www.asus.com/de/motherboards-components/motherboards/proart/proart-x670e-creator-wifi/helpdesk_qvl_cpu?model2Name=ProArt-X670E-CREATOR-WIFI

The first row (for my CPU) in the last column "Validated since BIOS" indicates that a BIOS of version 1303 is required.

Unfortunately, according to an imprint on my mainboard (which is the last 4 digits of a barcode next to the CPU, as described under https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044755/), it was only shipped with a BIOS of version 1003. So I think that I'll have to update my BIOS.

My problem: There's the following part of the ASUS homepage where one can download the different BIOS versions for my mainboard:

https://www.asus.com/de/motherboards-components/motherboards/proart/proart-x670e-creator-wifi/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=ProArt-X670E-CREATOR-WIFI

For the BIOS with version 1303, the following changelog is listed: "SoC voltage for Ryzen 7000X3D series limited to a maximum of 1.30V to protect the CPU and motherboard."

I have two questions:

1. I've also read somewhere on the internet, that an old BIOS together with one of the X3D CPUs might damage the CPU and mainboard. Does anyone know if this is true? If yes: How can I update my BIOS, if I can't start the mainboard with my CPU without damaging them?
2. Another problem is that my old computer is broken, so I don't have a computer available (I'm writing this from my phone) other than the new one I bought. So in order to get the new BIOS onto a USB stick, I would probably have to use my new PC, which might endanger the mainboard and CPU. Does anyone know if this would be dangerous?